# jQuery / Ckeditor - Update textarea and remove instance after focus out

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I work on a module translation.

I have more than 100 textarea on one page. To increase the load I create an instance on click.
When I quit the editor by clicking elsewhere, I want to update de textarea and remove the instance.

I do that but it doesn't work.

```
$('textarea').each(function(){

    // Ajout de l'instance
    $(this).click(function () {
        //$(this).ckeditor(config_editor);
        editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this,config_editor);
        console.log(editor);
        editor.focusout(function(e) {               
            if (e.editor.checkDirty()) console.log(e.editor.getData());
            e.editor.destroy();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: "I do that but it doesn't work." -- does it make bacon instead? How do you know it's not working? No CKE? Errors? Instances don't disappear? You feel a stinging pain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I paste the code of Man Programmer :

```
// Lancement de CKEDITOR
$('textarea').click(function () {

    editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this,config_editor);

    editor.on('blur', function(e){
        e.editor.destroy();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$('textarea').click(function () {
    //$(this).ckeditor(config_editor);
    console.log(this);
    editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this,config_editor);
    console.log(editor);
     editor.on('blur', function(e){
       if (e.editor.checkDirty()) console.log(e.editor.getData());
        e.editor.destroy();
    });

});
```

for dynamically added textarea

```
$(document).on('click','textarea',function(){
   //above code
});
```

Comment: Hi, it's change nothing. The creation works, it's the remove who doesn't work

Comment: I need to use `editor.destroy()`, but it's the event what I can find

Comment: Works ! Thank you very much for your help.